Why is BFQ19S not oscillating for uic and oscillating without uic?
The following is my schematics for FM transmitter.

Below is my netlist. Model for BFQ19S can be dowloaded from here (Infineon Link)
* FM_Transmitter
R2 VCC N004 15k
R3 N005 0 4.7k
R4 VCC N001 10k
R5 VCC N003 4.7k
R6 N004 0 6.8k
C1 N004 Vin 10µ
C2 N002 N001 2.2µ
V1 Vin 0 SINE(0 1 10Meg) AC 1
C3 Vout N007 2p
C4 N003 0 .1µ
C5 VCC Vout 20p
L1 VCC Vout 100n
R7 N006 0 220
V2 VCC 0 9
C7 N006 0 2p
R1 N007 0 50
C6 Vout N006 4.7p
C8 N005 0 10µ
R8 N003 0 2.2k
R9 N003 N002 1k
R10 VCC Vin 1k
C9 VCC 0 .1µ
XU1 N001 N004 N005 BFQ19S
XU2 Vout N003 N006 BFQ19S

.tran 100n 50u 0 100n uic
;ac oct 1 1k 800Meg
.include Infineon-RFTransistor-SPICE.lib-SM-v02_10-EN.lib

.control
run
*print all

plot v(Vout)

.endc


.end

This will generate this no oscillation graph.

However, you will get this circuit to oscillate if you remove uic in transient.

I am going to build this in real life to debunk the myth. My question is, which one is the real scenario?

Likely neither. In real life your components and their interconnections are not ideal. Even each piece of wiring between two components has inductance and capacitance, and the other components are even more complex.

@Justme Do you mean simulation is meaningless?

Neither is real.  You are bumping into one of the more basic behaviors of a numerical simulator.
Without uic, an operating point is calculated (.op), meaning the circuit is initialized with nothing in motion, and subsequent changes are calculated from that.  In particular, depending on settings and circuit behavior, it may never start up because the change from the previous step is within rounding error, gets truncated, and so on.
For uic, no initial conditions have been set, i.e. everything starts at zero by default, and a large transient ensues.  Once everything stabilizes, the circuit might be in a different state than .op would give, and gain/phase can be different.  Again the above case applies.
Note that, in the latter case, the timestep is initially small (while detailing the startup transient), but as it settles out, change per step decreases, and the timestep is gradually increased (by an amount related to TRTOL I believe?), which makes the simulation more efficient.  This necessarily makes the simulation less sensitive to short-term variations, such as numerical noise that might otherwise excite the system and grow and compound into full oscillation.
With nothing in motion, the first case also starts at maximum timestep.  You have a different mystery here, in fact: why the first case starts up at all, and the other apparently doesn't.  But, it's no mystery why it takes so long to get there.
As for the real circuit?  You'll hardly be able to capture a 100MHz wave, with good fidelity, within the first 50µs of operation.  Probing and acquiring this waveform is a non-trivial task.  Heck, supply voltage won't even be stable in that time: contact bounce almost guarantees intermittent supply for the first some ~ms, providing partial bias, odd initial voltages, and transient excitation to kick off the oscillator.  In addition, real circuits have thermal noise, while transient analysis doesn't by default (you have to add them in manually).  An unstable real circuit is guaranteed to start, but an unstable simulated circuit can be rounded down to local stability ("local" as in, within a factor of RELTOL, or ± VNTOL, CHGTOL, etc. as the case may be).
Two improvements must be made:

Reduce maximum timestep to at least a modest fraction of the maximum operating frequency or harmonics.  For a FM BCB oscillator, under 10ns is required.
Add a noise source or other stimulus to the system, and use .op conditions.  This can be as simple as a one-time voltage step of 1mV in series with C5.  A PULSE of 10ns delay, 1ns rise/fall, 1s duration, 2s period is as good as one-time for a simulation of this detail.


I think  .op  is used to calculate quiescent point. Does .op have anything to do with noise source? BTW, why did you choose the noise source in series with  C5 rather with the voltage source?

Yes, .op is the quiescent point analysis. It has nothing to do with noise or sources. A stimulus source can be placed most anywhere on the right-hand side (current to a node, or voltage in series with a component), the dominant reactive components are simply the most likely/effective candidates (C5, L1; C6 to a lesser extent; C4, etc.).

Every component in circuit has noise.
Why do you think dominant reactive components are the most likely candidate instead of BJT transistors?

No that's the point, components do not have noise in transient analysis, see: https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/transient_noise/50199768 and related docs. You have to construct a noise model yourself by adding sources. All that's needed is a suitable transient to get oscillation started, any noise (as such) is not necessary and would unnecessarily slow the simulation.

Do I still need uic for this case? My 16GB RAM memory is not enough for 10 ns step. Can you simulate on your end?

Just how long are you letting it run for? There isn't much you learn beyond the first few microseconds once amplitude stabilizes.

50u with uic. Can you show how you build this noise model with schematics and netlist?

Again, you don't need noise here... just a stimulus to kick it started...

should I put this stimulus in series with C5? Do I have to use uic in transient ?
